# How to specify -X in ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh

I would like to further alias my login to include the `-X` flag I find myself typing over and over again.

Current usage:

```
ssh -X myserver
```

Desired usage:

```
ssh myserver
```

Current `~/.ssh/config` entry:

```
Host myserver
  Hostname     172.18.0.17
  User         root
  Port         1234
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand???
```

I'm reading the manpage again but there isn't a clear mapping between flags and keywords in my opinion: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html

Answer (score 0):

The `-X` option appears to correspond to the `ForwardX11` keyword.

```
Host myserver
  Hostname     172.18.0.17
  User         root
  Port         1234
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ForwardX11   yes
```